# Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync often takes a long time to attach and internal format error occurs

Tags: outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

An error occurs when trying to attach a file by calling Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync from the Office 365 Outlook add-in (on the web).

This happens frequently right after loading the Outlook website. It may not occur after some time after loading.
It occurs in IE, Chrome (on Windows10, on Mac) and Safari (on Mac). There is no problem with Desktop version.

This has not happened before, but it has recently occurred.
There have been no changes to the Outlook add-in in the last few months.

I created and tested the following simple program. The same error occurs in this program.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#send-btn").click(function () {
            try {
                var url = "https://www.cloudstoragelight.com/proaxiastorage/f/Demo/TestData.xlsx";
                var attachemrtFilename = "TestData.xlsx";
                debugger;
                Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
                    url,
                    attachemrtFilename,
                    { asyncContext: null },
                    function (asyncResult) {
                        if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                            if (asyncResult.error && asyncResult.error.message) {
                                console.log("Error(" + asyncResult.error.message + ")");
                            } else {
                                console.log("Error");
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("SUCCESS");
                        }
                    });
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.message) {
                    console.log("Error(" + e.message + ")");
                } else {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Is there any workaround?

[additional information]
I tried debugging with outlook-web-16.01.debug.js.

Looking at the contents of the stack when an error occurs, there is a _checkMethodTimeout function. The timeout judgment of this function has become true, and Callback has been called.

In this case, Microsoft.Office.Common.ClientEndPoint.invoke function sends the following message in postMessage.

{"_messageType": 0, "_actionName": "ExecuteMethod", "_conversationId": "7cc28a93_6a3c12a5_1581127643048", "_correlationId": 5, "_origin": "https: // localhost: 44313 / MessageRead.html? et =", "_data": {"ApiParams": {"uri": "https://www.cloudstoragelight.com/proaxiastorage/f/Demo/TestData.xlsx", "name": "TestData.xlsx", "isInline": false, "__ timeout __": 600000}, "MethodData": {"ControlId": "963d4dfe-eaad-8e5b-6fa5-3eaac31b660d", "DispatchId": 16}}, "_ actionType": 0, "_ serializerVersion": 1}

Comment: We are not able to reproduce this error with the same code that you've provided. What is the error message / error code you're getting from the API call?

Comment: I get the following error.

"There was an internal format error."

Comment: Could you clarify on when exactly the issue occurs? Does it happen when you load the OWA page, immediately open the add-in and click on the "#send-btn"? Does it repeatedly happen or only once or twice after the add-in is launched?

Comment: It happen when I load the OWA page, immediately open the add-in and click on the "#send-btn".
It repeatedly happen.

Comment: When I checked this issue today, the add-in error was gone.

Comment: We could not repro this issue on our end. Please let us know if you face this issue again.